# What is the logic behind the method for finding horizontal asymptote of a rational function?

Tags: functions, asymptotics, rational-functions

I know the methods perfectly well but I don't understand why they are the way they are. For example, finding the vertical asymptote makes perfect sense as setting the denominator to 0 just finds you the values of x that undefines the function. However, I don't see any logic behind the methods to find the horizontal asymptotes and it doesn't make any intuitive sense to me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Just take limits as $x \to \pm \infty$. Can you clarify what's the problem?